# Angular/Ionic: Can't access value in html input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following HTML code:

```
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input id="email" ng-model="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
            </label>
            <br> 
            <center>
            <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="getData();"> Test </button>
             </center>
        </div>
```

And the following Angular code:

```
    $scope.getData = function() {
        var emailadd = document.getElementById('email');
        var url = "http://172.16.99.138/sendemail.php?emailaddress="+emailadd;
        console.log(url);
    };
```

However when I try to run the code, the console says that it can't find the variable. Would appreciate guidance here.

Comment: Can you elaborate please

Comment: Don't use the dom elements for bindings like this, that's the main point of using angular, 2-way-binding..

Comment: Still a bit confused as to how I should solve this. New to angular here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Your code in question is wrong anyway as `document.getElementById('email')` will get you the dom element, this is not the `value()` of the element.

**Still you should be doing this the "Angular Way" :**

You need to define the model in your Controller like so :

```
  $scope.email = {
    text: ''
  };
```

Then you can bind in the HTML like so :

```
<input type="email" name="input" ng-model="email.text" required>
```

Then you can use the `$scope.email` in your method :

```
$scope.getData = function() {
   var url = "http://172.16.99.138/sendemail.php?emailaddress="+$scope.email.text;
   console.log(url);
};
```

[ng-model Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D)

Comment: It is not necessary i think, to create object only to catch that input value.Angular it is more useful and beautiful :)

Comment: @FationHadri assume the user would like to store the observable elsewhere, or infact he has complex objects, or he has resolved the value elsewhere in a service, he must then manage more on the front-view end. It's usualy good practice to maintain less in the view. 

But your answer works perfectly too for the OP's issue.

Comment: @Pogrindis, Yes, i agree with you,but here we have a simple situation and it doesn't make sense to me that object created in controller.I think it is not right.He don't want to have a static email.It is input.You do not limit the user what he should write in email.Sorry but i think you have made a big mistake here.

Comment: @FationHadri big mistake would be a little over-exaggerated, but I have removed the static email for brevity. -> To help explain - in your example, how would you populate the fields from the database on arrival for example ? -> If you do not have #scope.email defined in controller.. It will not be too useful.

Comment: @Pogrindis, If we disscuss on what he might have to do,we ,will find a lot.I specified" big mistake" based on your reputation :)

Comment: ReEputation is just a number, I prefer to answer the questions with future proof in mind! ;]

Answer (score 1):

Use this way of data binding in AngularJs,pass email as parameter in function getData()

```
<div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input id="email" ng-model="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
            </label>
            <br> 
            <center>
            <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="getData(email);"> Test </button>
             </center>
        </div>
```

And in your controller

```
  $scope.getData = function(email) {
       // var emailadd = document.getElementById('email');don't use this
        var url = "http://172.16.99.138/sendemail.php?emailaddress="+email;
        console.log(url);
    };
```